# How do I load the R dataset biospy from MASS package into python?

Tags: python

I am trying to load biospy dataset from MASS package in R into python.
But my code is getting me http 404 not found error , in reality there is a biospy dataset in R under MASS package. Does anyone know how to get through this?

## Code

```
import statsmodels.api as sm
biospy=sm.datasets.get_rdataset("biospy","MASS")
```

## Error

> HTTPError: HTTP Error 404: Not Found
>
> During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:
>
> ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call
>   last)  in 
>         1 
>   ----> 2 biospy=sm.datasets.get_rdataset("biospy","MASS") ValueError: Dataset biospy was not found.

Answer (score 1):

You have mistyped "biopsy" as "biospy", which is leading to the dataset not being found.

Answer (score 0):

It should be in single quotes or may be missing packages.

Install packages:

```
pip install --user statsmodels && pip install --user spicy
```

Try:

```
biopsy_set = sm.datasets.get_rdataset('biopsy','MASS')`l
```

Ref:

1. https://kolesnikov.ga/Datasets_in_Python/
2. https://repl.it/repls/PrudentFamousPostgres

Comment: Double and single quoted strings in Python are the same, so that shouldn't be the issue